# php codeigniter base_url not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, path

I am currently using codeigniter to write out templates for a website.  The problem is that I'm trying to achieve absolute paths for attributes such as `href` and `src`, but they aren't working.  I've checked my results, and the link's and scripts point through the correct directory, so I'm not sure why there is a problem.

This is the code I'm using below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() . "assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"; ?>">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() . "assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css"; ?>">

        <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="<?php echo base_url() . "assets/html5shiv/html5shiv.js"; ?>"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <!-- Fav and touch icons go here -->


    </head>
<body>
    <p>This comes from the header view.</p>

    <button class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
    <br />
    <a class="btn btn-primary">Secondary</a>
```

I can tell that this isn't working because I'm trying to use bootstrap to style two buttons, but they aren't working.  Can someone please help me figure this out?

Oh, by the way..my base_url is `http://localhost/ProjectName/`, and I know that I have this working correctly because I have enabled the URL helper and I am able to echo the base_url.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that You've loaded URL helper, in your autoload.php, and also make sure that you've added defined base_url in your config.php.
if not then this should help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you haven't edited codeigniter files to enable **base_url()**. you try to assingn it in url_helper.php you also can do the same config/autoload.php file. you can add this code in your autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to drop in and out of PHP. You can just do this:

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

if this doesn't work there's a problem with where your css files are.

Comment: why would there be a problem with where my css files are located?

Comment: base_url() contains your base URL. If your css are in /application/assets you need to add /application to the reference string:

link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() . "application/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css"; ?>">

or

link rel="stylesheet" href="/application/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />